# I am trying to change my if statement to a for loop using php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Basically I want to validate user input to ensure they are entering integer values. My if statement works well but my assignment is to change it to a for loop. Thanks!

my original if statement;

```php
if (empty($scores[0]) ||
    empty($scores[1]) ||
    empty($scores[2]) ||
    !is_numeric($scores[0]) ||
    !is_numeric($scores[1]) ||
    !is_numeric($scores[2])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a for loop to validate inputs? Doesn't make much sense. And you need a number in the for loop to count the iterations. What's that going to be?

Comment: @ngearing I completely agree. It's for my college assignment. The practice doesn't make sense to me either and I am getting frustrated.

Comment: Just an aside, you don't need to call `empty` as well as `!is_numeric`, as `is_numeric('') === false`

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use a `for` loop to validate the scores, then you just need to test each value in the `$scores` array in it:

```php
$scores_string = '';
$len = count($scores);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if (empty($scores[$i]) || !is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        break;
    }
}
if ($scores_string != '') {
    echo $scores_string;
    // do anything else you need
}
else {
    // all is OK!
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZDtND)

Note that the `break` in the `if` after you assign `$scores_string` saves iterating the entire array after a non-numeric value was found. If you wanted to count the number of non-numeric values, you'd increment a counter there instead.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Nick this should do it! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define a function that returns a boolean to validate the parameters. If one variable of the parameters is invalid, return false immediately. Otherwise, return true.

Then use the function directly.

Check out the code below:

```
function isNumberScores($scores) {
    foreach($socres as $score) {
        if (empty($score) || !is_numeric($score)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

if (!isNumberScores($socres)) {
    $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: My college assignment is to change my code using for loop only which is why I am struggling. It doesn't seem like good practice and I am confused why this is a requirement. Thanks for your post though

Comment: The solutions are similar. You could change the code a bit little to fix your work.

Comment: This answer has typos and does not appear to demand indexes `0`, `1`, and `2` exist.  It does not make sense to call `empty()` within the context of this loop.  The variable will always be declared so just use a falsey check.   ... but that will prohibit zeros as valid integers -- I don't know the business requirements on that bit.